# background fade-out and going to another page

Tags: java, android, xml, shapes, alpha

I have an XML layout page with a gradient background. I also have an anim XML page to change the alpha from 1 to 0 and a drawable xml page to define a shape as background of layout page.
What I'm trying to do is to fade-out the background and then go to the second page. However, the project doesn't run.

drawable/linegradiant.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
 <gradient
    android:centerX="20%"
    android:endColor="#aed36c"
    android:startColor="#44c8f5" />
</shape>
```

anim/fade_out.xml

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromAlpha="1.0"
android:toAlpha="0.0"
android:duration="2000" >

</alpha>
```

MainActivity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/firstpage"
android:background="@drawable/linergradiant"

android:orientation="vertical" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/texture" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
        android:background="@drawable/logo_big2" >
    </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements AnimationListener {
 LinearLayout screen;
// Handler handler = new Handler();
 int i;
 Intent intent;
 Animation animFadeout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    screen=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.firstpage);
    animFadeout=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fade_out );
    animFadeout.setAnimationListener(this);

    screen.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            screen.startAnimation(animFadeout); 

        }
    });



}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BMIcalculator.class));

}
@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "project doen't run"? Is there an exception thrown? If yes, post the stack trace.

Comment: @Loop I mean it doesn't work and no error.if it has error and I can't solve it I put that error here too.

Comment: @mimi when is the time you want to change activity?? it is when the animation is done?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin yes exactly .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to start an activity from another thread which conflicts with the UI thread that it need to be called from there. also it is unnecessary to call the `screen.startAnimation(animFadeout);` within another thread.

**solution:**

you need to use your listener of the animation to start activity when the animation is done.

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BMIcalculator.class));

}
```

and start the animation in the queue post of the `LinearLayout` so it is run synchronously

```
screen.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            screen.startAnimation(animFadeout); 

        }
    })
```

Dont use **thread** just to start an animation it is really unnecessary.

**UPDATED:**

You are not really using the animation that you created but you supply the id of the linear layout it should be the animation.

```
animFadeout=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fade_out);
```

Comment: I edit it as u said,I mean I delete my thread and add screen.post and also start activity when the animation is done. but it doesn't work. what can I don now, it doesn't have any error.

Comment: I update my code as u said here .mind me ask u to look at them ??

Comment: @mimi change the `getApplicationContext()` to `this`

Comment: sorry but It has another problem if I can ask u? when the duration finish(background fade out ) and it want to go to another page for one second background appear in screen.what can I do with this problem?

Comment: @mimi that would be another post. GO post it. to clarify your problem, with some code.